# Get child class from parent

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have a big issue in Swift programming. I am trying to get the name of child class from the parent. This is a sample example, what i want to do:

```
class Parent {
  class func sayHello() {
      let nameChildClass = //
      println("hi \(nameChildClass)")
  }
}

class Mother: Parent {

}

class Father: Parent {

}

Mother.sayHello()
Father.sayHello()
```

I know there is some other way do to that, but i really need to it like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
func getRawClassName(object: AnyClass) -> String {
    let name = NSStringFromClass(object)
    let components = name.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    return components.last ?? "Unknown"
}
```

which takes an instance of a class and obtain the type name using `NSStringFromClass`.

But the type name includes the namespace, so to get rid of that it's split into an array, using the dot as separator - the actual class name is the last item of the returned array.

You can use it as follows:

```
class Parent {
    class func sayHello() {
        println("hi \(getRawClassName(self))")
    }
}
```

and that will print the name of the actual inherited class

Answer (score 6):

From Swift 5.2

```
String(describing: Self.self)
```

Comment: This is the best answer now

Answer (score -2):

You have to override the `sayHello` function in your child classes:

```
class Parent {
  class func sayHello() {
      println("base class")
  }
}

class Mother: Parent {
    override func sayHello() {
        println("mother")
    }
}

class Father: Parent {
    override func sayHello() {
        println("father")
    }
}

mother = Mother()
father = Father()

mother.sayHello()
father.sayHello()
```

Comment: I know this trick, but if it's possible i want to it in the parent class.

Comment: The child class know of its parent class but the parent class doesn't know anything about its descendants. You can always check of which type an _instance_ is, though.

Comment: ok thanks for your help it's quite difficult, even impossible i think, the solution i found is to pass the class in parameter : class func sayHello(class: AnyClass)